# Service Worker slow response times

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

In Windows and Android Google Chrome browser, (haven't tested for others yet) response time from a **service worker** increases linearly to number of items stored in that specific **cache storage** when you use [Cache.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/match) function with following option;

```
ignoreSearch = true
```

Dividing items in multiple caches helps but not always convenient to do so. Plus even a small amount of increase in items stored makes a lot of difference in response times. According to my measurements response time is roughly doubled for every tenfold increase in number of items in the cache.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Official answer to my [question in chromium issue tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=682677) reveals that the problem is a known performance issue with Cache Storage implementation in Chrome which only happens when you use `Cache.match()` with `ignoreSearch` parameter set to `true`.

As you might know `ignoreSearch` is used to disregard query parameters in URL while matching the request against responses in cache. [Quote from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/match#Parameters):

> ...whether to ignore the query string in the url.  For example, if set to
> true the ?value=bar part of http://example.com/?value=bar would be ignored
> when performing a match.

Since it is not really convenient to stop using query parameter match, I have come up with following workaround, and I am posting it here in hopes of it will save time for someone;

```js
// if the request has query parameters, `hasQuery` will be set to `true`
var hasQuery = event.request.url.indexOf('?') != -1;

event.respondWith(
  caches.match(event.request, {
    // ignore query section of the URL based on our variable
    ignoreSearch: hasQuery,
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    // handle the response
  })
);
```

This works great because it handles every request *with* a query parameter correctly while handling others still at lightning speed. And you do not have to change anything else in your application.

Comment: Excellent!!!, wish that you could complete the event.respondWith() code.

Comment: @MahmoudAliKassem Sure, here you go. Updated the code snippet to be complete working code. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [guy in that bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=682677), the issue was tied to the number of items in a cache. I made a solution and took it to the extreme, giving each resource its own cache:

```js
var cachedUrls = [
    /* CACHE INJECT FROM GULP */
];

//update the cache
//don't worry StackOverflow, I call this only when the site tells the SW to update
function fetchCache() {
    return Promise.all(
        //for all urls
        cachedUrls.map(function(url) {
            //add a cache
            return caches.open('resource:'url).then(function(cache) {
                //add the url
                return cache.add(url);
            });
        });
    );
}
```

In the project we have here, there are static resources served with high cache expirations set, and we use query parameters (repository revision numbers, injected into the html) only as a way to manage the [browser] cache.
It didn't really work to use your solution to selectively use `ignoreSearch`, since we'd have to use it for all static resources anyway so that we could get cache hits!

However, not only did I dislike this hack, but it *still* performed very slowly.

---

Okay, so, given that it was only a specific set of resources I needed to `ignoreSearch` on, I decided to take a different route;
**just remove the parameters from the url requests manually, instead of relying on `ignoreSearch`.**

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    //find urls that only have numbers as parameters
    //yours will obviously differ, my queries to ignore were just repo revisions
    var shaved = event.request.url.match(/^([^?]*)[?]\d+$/);
    //extract the url without the query
    shaved = shaved && shaved[1];

    event.respondWith(
        //try to get the url from the cache.
        //if this is a resource, use the shaved url,
        //otherwise use the original request
        //(I assume it [can] contain post-data and stuff)
        caches.match(shaved || event.request).then(function(response) {
            //respond
            return response || fetch(event.request);
        })
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and previous approaches caused some errors with requests that should be *ignoreSearch:false*. An easy approach that worked for me was to simply apply *ignoreSearch:true* to a certain requests by using *url.contains('A') &&* ... See example below:

```js
    self.addEventListener("fetch", function(event) {
         
      var ignore
    
      if(event.request.url.includes('A') && event.request.url.includes('B') && event.request.url.includes('C')){
        ignore = true
      }else{
        ignore = false
      }
      event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request,{
            ignoreSearch:ignore, 
          })
          .then(function(cached) {
            ...
           }
```